# How to properly use log4j while having two maven web modules?

Tags: java, maven, spring-mvc, tomcat, log4j

I created the first maven web module (war) and configured log4j using log4j.properties. I placed the properties file in usr/main/resources and it worked. Then I added another maven web module and did the same configuration there, changing only the file path of the logger with the intention of having two log files for each application. I am getting no errors but it doesn't work after I deployed the second war in webserver (Tomcat). Now logging is not working even for the first application.

I tried even putting the log4j.properties outside wars and adding log4jlistener in web.xml but in this case the log file is being created but nothing is getting written. Any idea what may cause this? Is there another approach I should follow ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to have the jar files in each application so that they don't get confused.  If you just have the jar files in the common library, the system will get very confused.

Another issue is that some Maven artifacts have dependencies on the jar files that hurt the system.  You want to have the jar files for the implementations in the POM for the web application, but you don't want them in the jar files used by the web application.  There are multiple implementation jar files for the log4j (version 1.x) logging frameworks.  If you combine jar files from different implementations, the system will get confused.

See https://bradleyaross.wordpress.com/2016/05/05/java-logging-frameworks/

I had a add some dependencies and  exclusions to make things work.

Answer (score 0):

The page https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.0/manual/webapp.html describes how you should configure/setup log4j within a web application.

The paragraph *Approaches* within the https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.0/manual/logsep.html is describing how the web server can be configured to have different configurations per webapp.

Comment: Can you be more specific please? Where does this link address my question ?